# Batch file to rename text files within directory with text from within text file at specific line except if line blank

Tags: batch-file, error-handling

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
cd "C:\Documents and Settings\John\Desktop\New\Interest\f2"
Pushd "C:\Documents and Settings\John\Desktop\New\Interest\f2"
Set Line#=26
Set /A LOfs=24 -1, Len=34 - LOfs
For %%A in (*.txt) do For /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%B in (
  'Findstr /N ".*" "%%A" ^|Findstr "^%Line#%:"'
) do if %errorlevel% == 0 Set "Line=%%C"&Ren "%%~fA" "!Line:~%LOfs%,%Len%! - %%A!""
Popd
```

In the above I am trying to change the filename of files in a directory with text in it at a certain position.

If line 26 is blank do nothing and do not change filename.

I have gone wrong somewhere and am going round in circles.

Can anyone help?

Thank you.

Comment: why there are two quotes at the end of the `do` condition? This will set the ren command to the `line` variable value.

Comment: What `ErrorLevel` do you expect `if %ErrorLevel% == 0` to receive? the one of `findstr`? this cannot work, because `findstr` is executed by `for /F` in a new `cmd` instance. In addition, you'd need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for `!ErrorLevel!`; alternatively, you could use `if not ErrorLevel 1`. Anyway, since you are filtering for line # 26 anyway, you probably do not need any `if`/`ErrorLevel` query after all. There is a `"` too many after the `ren` command line. Nevertheless, you should provide an example, and you should describe what actually happens...

Comment: I thought that **if %ErrorLevel% == 0** would occur if **Findstr /N ".*" "%%A" ^|Findstr "^%Line#%:** was not a blank line.

Answer (score 0):

You don't state how your script fails, but I can see some potential problems. I also see possible simplifications.

- You certainly don't need both `CD` and `PUSHD`
- I got rid of the numeric variables and included the number literals in the actual code. You can revert back to variables if you want.
- You don't need the outer `FOR` loop. FINDSTR can search multiple files when using wildcards in the file name, and then it will include the filename, followed by `:` in the output. So if you add the `/N` option, output will have the form `filename:line#:text`. You can then adjust the 2nd `FINDSTR` to return only the correct line numbers.
- It is not enough to ignore blank lines. Your rename only works if there is at least one valid file name character after the 23rd character. Filenames cannot include `:`, `*`, `?`, `/`, `\`, `<`, `>`, or `|`. (I may have missed some). I adjusted the `FOR /F` delims and the `FINDSTR` search to compensate.
- FOR variable expansion like `%%A` will corrupt values if they contain `!` and delayed expansion is enabled. `!` is a valid character in file names. So the delayed expansion must be toggled on and off within the loop.

I believe the following will do what you want. The code below will simply echo the rename commands. Remove the `ECHO` before the `ren` once it gives the correct results.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
pushd "C:\Documents and Settings\John\Desktop\New\Interest\f2"
for /f "tokens=1,3 delims=:*?\/<>|" %%A in (
  'findstr /n "^" "*.txt" ^| findstr "^[^:]*:26:.......................[^:*?\\/<>|]"'
) do (
  set "old=%%A"
  set "line=%%B"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  ECHO ren "!old!" "!line:~23,11! - !old!"
  endlocal
)
popd
```

Comment: The usage of vars stem from my answer of OPs [first very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42278373/). He didn't show much own effort there nor honoured a complete answer. The above code was taken from my answer (and some errors added) when I refused to extend my answer to a new question.

Comment: @LotPings - Interesting history. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An slightly different method to Daves:

```cmd
@Echo Off

Set "SrcDir=%UserProfile%\Desktop\New\Interest\f2"
Set "Mask=*.txt"
Set "Line#=26"
Set "LOfs=23"
Set "Len=11"

If /I Not "%CD%"=="%SrcDir%" Pushd "%SrcDir%"2>Nul&&(Set _=T)||Exit/B

For /F "Tokens=1-2* Delims=:" %%A In ('FindStr/N "^" "%Mask%" 2^>Nul'
) Do If "%%B"=="%Line#%" If Not "%%~C"=="" (Set "Line=%%C"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    If Not "!Line:~%LOfs%,%Len%!"=="" (
        If Not Exist "!Line:~%LOfs%,%Len%! - %%A" (
            Ren "%%A" "!Line:~%LOfs%,%Len%! - %%A"))
    EndLocal)

If "_"=="T" PopD
```

Comment: Can anybody help in Compo's script I want to pass **!Line:~%LOfs%,%Len%!** to a variable so as to check that if text has a / which should be replaced by space but when I say **Set str="!Line:~%LOfs%,%Len%!"** and then **ECHO %str%** I get the output **ECHO is off.**. If I **ECHO "!Line:~%LOfs%,%Len%!"** I get output expected. All help appreciated. Thank you

Comment: That would technically be a different question. I would suggest you mark the answer which you prefer as correct and then begin a new question specific to your new requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This method don't require `findstr.exe` nor toggle `setlocal/endlocal`, so it should run faster. Also, it avoids to re-process any already renamed file changing the plain `for %%A` by a `for /F` combined with `dir` command.

```
@Echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cd "C:\Documents and Settings\John\Desktop\New\Interest\f2"
Set /A Line#=26, LOfs=24 -1, Len=34 - LOfs

For /F "delims=" %%A in ('dir /A-D /B *.txt') do (

   rem Read the desired line from this file
   (for /L %%i in (1,1,%Line#%) do set "Line=" & set /P "Line=") < "%%A"

   if defined Line ECHO Ren "%%~fA" "!Line:~%LOfs%,%Len%! - %%A"

)
```

Note also that when this Batch file ends the current directory is automatically recovered to the current one when `setlocal` command was executed, so `pushd/popd` commands are not needed either.

Comment: Sure, you avoid toggling delayed expansion, but it will now fail if the file name contains `!`. Also, in my hands, the FINDSTR solution is about 5 times faster at finding the 26th line than using FOR /L with SET /P.